# Pipe lsof to grep to awk ps -ef to grep

Tags: linux, awk, lsof

I'm trying to get some info on a certain PID. I'm probably doing this in a manner that is way too difficult, but I'm trying to run this:

```
lsof | grep grepstuff | awk '{ps -ef | grep $2;}'
```

and I'm not getting anything in response.

If I remove the `awk` part, I can definitely see that I am seeing the connections.

Comment: Seems you've figured out what you're looking for, but look into pgrep.

Comment: What information are you trying to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
lsof | awk '/grepstuff/ {ps $2;}'
```